# how to simplify (x+y')X(x+z')?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Hi this is for a Discrete Math test I have today. I can barely understand the simplification of boolean expressions. Can anyone show me if the (x+y')X(x+z') can be simplified further, what are the steps? The original question is [x'(y+z)]'(x+y'). I assume I did it correct up to the point (x+y')X(x+z').

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking it over. I think the distributive law states;
x+(yxz)=(x+y)X(x+z)     xX(y+z)=(xXy)+(xXz)

Therefore answer should be:
x+(y'X z').